# Como ordenar uma lista encadeada em ordem alfabética?

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Tenho que fazer um programa que crie uma lista encadeada contendo *structs* com informações de um participante(nome, cpf...). Já fiz a função inserir e quero ordenar a lista encadeada em outra função chamada ordenação.

Porém o programa dá ao executar a ordenação ou não a executa direito. Já busquei em vários sites mas não consegui achar resposta para a solução do meu problema.

```
void ordenacao(participante **primeiro, int tam)
{
    int i = 0, retorno;
    participante *anterior, *proximo, *aux, *aux2;

    if(tam > 1)
    {
            anterior = *primeiro;
            proximo = anterior->prox;

            while(proximo!=NULL)
            {
                    retorno = strcmp(anterior->nome, proximo->nome);

                   if(retorno > 0)
                   {
                        aux = anterior;
                        aux2 = proximo;
                        anterior->prox = proximo->prox;
                        proximo->prox = aux;
                        printf("Retorno = %d\n", retorno);
                   }
           i++;
           anterior = anterior->prox;
           proximo = proximo->prox;
           }
      }


system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Você já aprendeu a usar um debugador como o gdb? Com ele dá pra saber qual linha está dando erro, qual é o estado da pilha na hora do erro e mais  um monte de coisas.

Comment: mudando de assunto, o stackoverflow funciona melhor com perguntas bem pontuais. Perguntas em que você copia o programa inteiro e pede ajuda para debugar um erro não especificado não são muito bem vistas...

Comment: Na funcao `ordenacao()` podes precisar de alterar o `*primeiro` mas não tens nenhuma instrução que faça isso.

Comment: você pode fazer um método que converta toda a string para maiúscula ou minuscula, e percorrer verificando qual char é maior ou menor, assim pode saber em que posição colocar o item, e eu recomendaria ordenar logo na inserção, pode vir a ser mais fácil e pratico.

Comment: Com um pouco de paciência eu escrevo aqui um quick sort para lista simplesmente encadeada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minha ideia para solucionar seu problema é usar o quick sort para ordenar sua lista simplesmente encadeada.

Para tal, vou usar aqui uma função `impl_comp` que vai comparar dois elementos da lista (vão ser passados os dados, não os nós da lista). `impl_comp` pode, então, ser implementada para comparar quaisquer dois dados que se deseja, como no caso é string, vamos usar `strcmp` por baixo.

## Quick sort

O quick sort é um algoritmo recursivo que se baseia na seleção de um pivô, na partição dos dados e na ordenação recursiva dessa partição.

Seu algoritmo é:

```
quicksort(tlista *lista):
    elemento pivô = seleciona_pivô(lista)
    tlista *menor, *maiorigual
    partição(lista, pivô, &menor, &maiorigual)
    menor = quicksort(menor)
    maiorigual = quicksort(maiorigual)
    se pivô faz parte da lista, e não foi inserido no maiorigual:
        apendar elemento pivô no final de menor
    apendar maiorigual no final de menor
    retorne menor

partição(tlista *lista, elemento pivô, tlista **menor_retorno, tlista **maiorigual_retorno):
    tlista *atual = lista
    tlista *menor_cauda = nulo
    tlista *maiorigual_cauda = nulo
    enquanto atual != nulo:
        tlista *próximo = lista->próximo
        atual->próximo = nulo
        se impl_cmp(atual->valor, pivô) < 0:
            // inserir na partição menor
            se menor_cauda == nulo:
                menor_cauda = atual
                *menor_retorno = menor_cauda
            senão:
                 menor_cauda->próximo = atual
                 menor_cauda = atual
       senão:
            // inserir na partição maior ou igual
            se maiorigual_cauda == nulo:
                maiorigual_cauda = atual
                *maiorigual_retorno = maiorigual_cauda
            senão:
                 maiorigual_cauda->próximo = atual
                 maiorigual_cauda = atual
        atual = próximo
```

### Tempo de execução

Ele tem tempo médio de execução na ordem de `o(n log n)`, sendo portanto comparável com outros algoritmos de ordenação linearítmicos (linear vezes logaritmo), como merge sort e heap sort: como essa notação é assintótica, representando apenas o comportamento dominante da função de tempo de execução, não leva em consideração termos de ordem menor nem se tem alguma constante multiplicando o termo dominante.

Segundo a Wikipedia, o tempo de execução do merge sort [pode ser 3 vezes mais rápido no caso médio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort?wprov=sfsi1). No pior caso, o quick sort necessita de tempo `o(n^2)` operações para ser executado. Outras funções de tempo quadrático são insertion sort, selection sort e bubble sort.

### Estabilidade

Um outro ponto interessante mencionar é que o quick sort não é um método de ordenação *estável*. Uma ordenação estável mantém a posição relativa de elementos de mesmo peso; por exemplo, se fôssemos ordenar por ordem alfabética, ignorando o caso, e tivéssemos como entrada `"ana", "jeff", "Ana"`, uma ordenação estável produziria necessariamente `"ana", "Ana", "jeff"`, mas talvez a saída do quick sort seja `"Ana", "ana", "jeff"`.

Saber se ordenações são estáveis é interessante quando se deseja organizar por múltiplos fatores distintos. Um caso desse tipo de ordenação poderia ser aplicado aqui no Stack Overflow em português (exemplo didático, não necessariamente prático): ordene as pessoas por ordem de pontos e, em caso de empate, priorize os mais recentes.

Para realizar essa ordenação, poderíamos usar uma ordenação por mais recentes e, depois, uma ordenação estável por pontos; como ordenamos inicialmente por mais recentes, a ordenação estável manterá essa ordem parcial quando for fazer a ordenação final.

### E essa brincadeira em C, como fica?

Primeiramente, quero construir com um nível de abstração aqui. Onde eu colocar `elemento` troque para o tipo realmente sendo usado. No presente caso, seria `char*`, por ser comparação de string. Em segundo lugar, estou postergando a implementação de `impl_cmp(elemento a, elemento b)` para que se possa usar a implementação adequada de comparação.

```
/* substitua "elemento" pelo tipo de dado utilizado */
typedef struct lista {
    elemento valor;
    struct lista *prox;
} tlista;

/* não se esqueça de implementar essa função */
int impl_cmp(elemento a, elemento b);

/* l_ret: retorno menor/lesser
 * ge_ret: retorno maior ou igual/greater equal
 */
void partition(tlista *lista, elemento pivot, tlista **l_ret, tlista **ge_ret) {
    tlista *l_tail = NULL;
    tlista *ge_tail = NULL;

    tlista *atual = lista;

    while (atual != NULL) {
        tlista *prox = atual->prox;

        atual->prox = NULL;
        if (impl_cmp(atual->valor, pivot) < 0) {
            if (l_tail == NULL) {
                 l_tail = atual;
                 *l_ret = l_tail;
            } else {
                l_tail->prox = atual;
                l_tail = atual;
            }
        } else {
            if (ge_tail == NULL) {
                 ge_tail = atual;
                 *ge_ret = ge_tail;
            } else {
                ge_tail->prox = atual;
                ge_tail = atual;
            }
        }
        atual = prox;
    }
}

tlista *concatena_3_listas(tlista *a, tlista *b, tlista *c) {
    tlista *head = a;
    tlista *tail = head;

    if (head != NULL) {
        head = tail = b;
    } else {
        while (tail->prox != NULL)  {
            tail = tail->prox;
        }
        tail->prox = b;
    }

    if (head != NULL) {
        head = tail = c;
    } else {
        while (tail->prox != NULL)  {
            tail = tail->prox;
        }
        tail->prox = c;
    }

    return head;
}

tlista *quicksort(tlista *lista) {
    /* vou pegar como pivot sempre o primeiro da lista, removendo-o de lá; poderia usar outra técnica, mas essa é boa o suficiente para o exemplo */
   tlista *pivot_lista = lista;
   elemento pivot = pivot_lista->valor;

   lista = lista->prox;
   pivot_lista->prox = NULL;

   tlista *menor, *maior;

   menor = maior = NULL;

   partition(lista, pivot, &menor, &maior);

   menor = quicksort(menor);
   maior = quicksort(maior);

  return concatena_3_listas(menor, pivot_lista, maior);
}
```

### Notas sobre a comparação com a implementação sobre vetor

Quando se usa o quicksort *in loco* em um vetor, sempre se envia para as funções recursivas qual o começo e qual o fim de cada conjunto de elementos nas chamadas recursivas de partição e de quicksort. Também, quando o pivô faz parte do vetor, faz-se um último *swap* do último elemento do subvetor de elementos menores com o pivô (que normalmente fica na primeira posição do vetor; se ele ficar na última, troca-se com o primeiro elemento do subvetor de elementos maiores ou iguais).

Como a estrutura de dados de lista simplesmente encadeada traz consigo a noção de começo (o ponteiro da lista é o começo dela mesma) e de fim (último elemento existente cujo próximo elemento é nulo), não é necessário ficar passando essa informação adiante.

Comment: Muito boa explicação; só um detalhe, que a expressão latina é _in loco_ (_locus_ vai para o ablativo)... ;-)

Comment: @Wtrmute isso que dar faltar às aulas de latim xD Obrigado pela correção

Comment: Muito boa explicação @JeffersonQuesado ! Me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa de dois loops para funcionar, o algoritmo é o bubble sort;

```
void ordenar(lista **l) {

    if(*l == NULL || (*l)->prox == NULL) return; //se for nulo(vazio), ou apenas 1 elemento
    lista *aux = *l, *t;
    char s[100]; //precisa de espacao suficiente para armazenar o nome

    while(aux != NULL) {
      t = aux->prox;
      while(t != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(aux->nome, t->nome) > 0) { //se vir depois
            strcpy(s, aux->nome);
            strcpy(aux->nome, t->nome);
            strcpy(t->nome, s);
        }
        t = t->prox;
      }
      aux = aux->prox;
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/nidDTe

Comment: Não precisa de strcpy se for só manipulação de ponteiros; só fazer o seguinte: `s = aux->nome; aux->nome = t->nome; t->nome = s;` Isso também evita possíveis problemas que talvez tenha pela alocação de strings de tamanhos diversos que você fez ao criar os nós no código do ideone

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado se for string precisa sim!