# Vetor de objetos em C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classificação

Como faço um vetor de objetos utilizando c++? E como faço para ordenar esse vetor de objetos, por exemplo, utilizando algum algoritmo de ordenação (quicksort, mergesort, shellsort ou radixsort)?

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

class Game {
public:
float preco;
char nome[25];
int idade;
char categoria[30];

};

int main (){
Game *jogo = new Game();
int i;

//for (i=0; i < 2; i++){
cout <<"Digite o preço do jogo: \n";
cin >> jogo->preco;
cout <<"Digite a nome do jogo: \n";
cin >> jogo->nome;
cout <<"Digite a idade indicativa para joga-lo : \n";
cin >> jogo->idade;
cout <<"Qual a categoria do jogo: \n";
cin >> jogo->categoria;
//}

cout << jogo->preco <<"\n";
cout << jogo->nome << "\n";
cout << jogo->idade << "\n";
cout << jogo->categoria << "\n";


return 0;   

}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210524/64969; tem toda uma base teórica interessante, apesar de ser sobre lista encadeada

Comment: Não sou fã deste tipo de código porque ele é meio C e mio C++, fico até sem saber o que ofereço já que não sei se quer programar em C ou C++. Parece que é C++, aí esse código deveria ser reescrito.

Comment: @Maniero seria interanssante se você tivesse indicado para ele oque ele deveria mudar no código e não simplesmente mandalo reescrevê lo...

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Use a biblioteca que o C++ te oferece.

O seu código parece de C, não de C++. Você pode usar a [STL](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/PRGSWB/STL/stl.html) para deixar seu código mais simples e claro.

## 2. "using namespace std" é uma péssima prática.

Quando você escreve `using namespace std`, você está importando toda a `std` para a namespace global e isso pode causar conflitos com outra biblioteca.

## 3. Você não precisa usar ponteiros para criar variáveis

Usar ponteiros é desnecessário no seu caso, pois, se você não desalocar ele usando `delete`, você pode ter um [Memory Leak](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++MemoryCorruptionAndMemoryLeaks.html).

## 4. Você está fazendo uma confusão de linguas

Escreva seu código em inglês para deixá-lo mais elegante e menos confuso. E se você não sabe inglês, não tenha preguiça de aprender.

---

O código deveria ser reescrito assim:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>   

struct Game {
    float price;
    std::string name;
    int min_age;
    std::string category;
};

int main (){
    Game game;

    std::cout << "Digite o preço do jogo: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> game.price;
    std::cout << "Digite a nome do jogo: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> game.name;
    std::cout << "Digite a idade indicativa para joga-lo: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> game.min_age;
    std::cout << "Qual a categoria do jogo: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> game.category;

    std::cout << game.price << std::endl;
    std::cout << game.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << game.min_age << std::endl;
    std::cout << game.category << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;   

}
```

Mesmo não sendo isso o que você quer, você pode fazer o que você quiser a partir dessas boas práticas.

Answer (score 0):

Para cada posição no Array você deve criar um novo objeto e inserir na devida posição. E para ordenar, escolha um dos atributos da classe como nome ou idade para servir de índice da ordenação.