# Criar função para ordenar alfabeticamente

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_pessoa{

  char nome[100];

  char matricula[100];

  long int curso;
}
pessoa;

void ordena(pessoa aluno[]){

//aqui é para ordenar o nome por ordem alfabética

 
}




int main(void) {

  pessoa aluno[5];

  int i, n=5;

  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Nome do aluno %d \n", (i+1));

    fgets(aluno[i].nome,100,stdin);

    printf("Matricula: \n");

    fgets(aluno[i].matricula,100,stdin);

    printf("Curso:  \n");

    scanf("%ld", &aluno[i].curso);

    getchar();
  }

}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta respota. Atende bem seu problema.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92516/como-ordenar-uma-lista-encadeada-em-ordem-alfab%C3%A9tica

Answer (score 1):

Depois de ralar muito, finalmente cosegui. Fazia anos que não usava C++, quem dirá C.
Segue o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// odernar a lista em ordem alfabetica


int main() {
    const char* to_ord[] = { "Joao", "Maria", "Joseh", "Joana", "Joauo", "Pedro", "Miguel", "Anja", "Aboemir" };

    int tam = sizeof(to_ord) / sizeof(char*);
    for (int x = 0; x < tam; ++x) {
        for (int y = x; y < tam; ++y) {
            if (strcmp(to_ord[x], to_ord[y]) == 1) {
                char* old = (char*)to_ord[x];
                to_ord[x] = (char*)to_ord[y];
                to_ord[y] = (char*)old;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < tam; ++x) {
        printf("%s\n", to_ord[x]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Explicando:

- Eu uso a func `strcmp` para saber qual das 2 strings é "maior alfabeticamente".
- Daí eu só faço esta comparação para todas da minha lista e troco se for maior.

Pra entender melhor é sobre o algoritmo de ordenação utilizado, [clique aqui](http://devfuria.com.br/logica-de-programacao/exemplos-na-linguagem-c-do-algoritmo-bubble-sort/). Pra documentação do `strcmp`, [clique aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcmp-wcscmp-mbscmp?view=msvc-160).